# Meaning of Trice

Tags: meaning

Could the word 'trice' mean a sixtieth of a second, being the third order of diminishing magnitude? 'Tierce' in French means 'a third'.

Comment: A trice is a crore of jiffies.

Comment: https://www.etymonline.com/word/trice and from M-W [a brief space of time, an instant](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trice) **Etymology** *Middle English trise, literally, pull, from trisen*

Comment: Apparently the etymology is Germanic rather than Romance and is based on earlier word meaning hoist or pulley

Comment: @John Lawler That makes a jiffy to be a hundred nanotrices. Very useful in today's world. But we digress. [World Today](https://www.world-today-news.com/nanotrices-and-respirators-can-be-used-repeatedly/).